# Working on a form option that has more than 2 options in it

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am making a social media chatroom website and I am currently making the signup page. The page had 2 genders to choose from:

- Male
- Female

but now I want to add "other" for anyone who doesn't identify as male or female. I have been working on code changes but I'm not sure what to put in my `$DATA.OBJ` line.

Here is my current script:

```js
$data['gender'] = $DATA_OBJ -> gender;
if (empty($DATA_OBJ -> gender)) {
    $Error.= "Please select a valid gender . <br>";
} else {
    if ($DATA_OBJ -> gender != "Male" && $DATA_OBJ -> gender != "Female" && $DATA_OBJ -> gender != "Other") {
        $Error.= "Please select a gender . <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please clarify your problem?

Comment: Thank you Abbas... My question is how do I add the other option to the poll bit without the "&&" feature? I have 3 options in my signup poll and the "&&" seems to just be for 2 options... it's not working for 3 options.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues with having as many `&&` operations in your `if` statement, as you want. Do you get any errors from your code?

Comment: I doubt, that the posted code is the problem. This is just the validation.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help, I used alert(result); and got the result that the issue was in this bit:

     $data['gender'] = $DATA_OBJ->gender;
    if(empty($DATA_OBJ->gender))

(the first two lines)

Comment: The problem is obviously already before this code - probably in the population of  

$DATA_OBJ -> gender;  ---   I also do not understand the first line as this array is not used in the posted code later on??   you assign the value of the property gender to $data[''gender and this array is not used ? why?   It is also a little strange to assign the value FIRST and THEN ask if the property is empty?

Comment: Okay, thank you everyone. I have been able to sort out the issue. I now have all three options fully functioning. Thanks for your help